# tensorflow group or collect fetches ops or tensors into single fetch

Tags: python-2.7, logging, tensorflow

I would like to do for the general case what tf.merge_all_summaries does for tf.get_collection('summaries').

As an example, I find that the tf.contrib.metrics.streaming* suite introduces a set of "update_op" operations that must be run once each. I find the following syntax too cumbersome,

```
_,_,_,_,_,summary,_=sess.run( tf.get_collection('updates')+[merged_summaries]+[train_op])
```

and I am looking for a workaround that does not require knowing the number of updates in the collection. I am using tensorflow-0.10 as of this writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow now supports (since version 0.10) passing **nested** structures to `Session.run()`. For example, you can now pass a list of lists of `tf.Tensor` objects to `Session.run()` and the result will be a similarly-nested list of lists of NumPy arrays. You can also pass a mixed list (or tuple) containing lists, tensors, and operations. In your case, you could write the following:

```
updates = tf.get_collection('updates')
_, summary, _ = sess.run([updates, merged_summaries, train_op])
```

In this case, the return value from `sess.run()` is a list with three elements, where the first (ignored) element is a list with the same length as `updates`.